# Node.js doesn't accept auth indirect to database in mongodb

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb

I have a problem that node.js doesn't accept user and password in admin database with mongodb . It need the user and password that have with database. What I want to know are there any solutions for this because in php it can connect to database with user and password in admin database and I have to change code from php to node.js. Another problem server won't allow me to add user and password direct with database because php can do it. So I want to know have any solution to this or I have to set user and password direct to database ?

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: mongodb i use is v2.6.11

Answer (score 0):

You should use mongodb v3.0.0. Then you can set user, password as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088963/how-to-create-a-user-in-mongodb-v3-0-5/32089876#32089876).

See also this [tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/add-user-administrator/).
Hope it helps you.

Comment: the point that you give me I have to set user and password direct with database ? but the main is php can do it with user and password set in admin database and it can connect other database .